# Creating a .each() function with proper syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dry

This is a bit of a noob question, so I apologize in advance. Basically I've got a bunch of these little code snippets:

```
$('#botBox').on('click', '#quest11',function(){
    $("#divContent1").hide().html(quest11).fadeIn(500);
});     
$('#botBox').on('click', '#quest12',function(){
    $("#divContent1").hide().html(quest12).fadeIn(500);
});                 
$('#botBox').on('click', '#quest13',function(){
    $("#divContent1").hide().html(quest13).fadeIn(500);
});
```

and as you can see it's essentially the same code over and over again, and I'd like to create an .each function rather than having a bunch of redundant code.

The markup it's referring to:

```
               <p id="quest11" class="quest">C'est quoi?</p>
               <p id="quest12" class="quest">Avantages</p>
```

The strings it's referring to:

```
var quest11 = "blah blah";
var quest12 = "blah blah blah";
```

so on and so forth.

This is what I came up with:

```
   $(".quest").each(function(){
            $('#botBox').on('click','#' + $(this).attr("id"),function(){
                $("#divContent1").hide().html($(this).attr("id")).fadeIn(500);
            });     
    });
```

The problem with this is that the .html() output will quite literally be ID as a string. In other words, the output for quest12 would be "quest12" rather than "blah blah blah".

In this example, how would I make it so quest12 is interpreted as the variable quest12 and not a string?

Comment: Are you using .each() specifically to learn how to use it in this context? You could create a class for all of them and easily perform the function you want with $(this).attr(id) to get the item clicked

Comment: You're misunderstanding the .each function, it is meant to iterate over a group of things, so say you wanted to get all the ids from every div that has a class of quest.void's answer below should do what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Please don't use `$(this).attr("id")`, the DOM sends this over just fine. `this.id` is much simpler.

Comment: The quests are numbered, which begs for an array. Perhaps using an array will make a solution more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an object to hold the different text:

```
var quests = {
  quest11 : "blah blah",
  quest12 : "blah blah blah"
}
```

Then use the `'[id^=quest]'` "attribute-starts-with" selector to delegate all `quest` elements to `botBox`.

Then you can simply use `this.id` to get the id of the clicked quest, and use it as the key of the `quests` object.

```
// All quest elements ----v---------v
$('#botBox').on('click', '[id^=quest]', function() {
    $("#divContent1").hide().html(quests[this.id]).fadeIn(500);
}); // Use the ID of the element --------^-----^
```

Comment: The only answer in this thread that worked, for whatever reason. Thank you!

Comment: @FelixMaxime: You're welcome. Yeah, they were close but didn't really read your code too carefully. The `eval` answer technically would work but it's the mother of all anti-patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(".quest").click(function(){
    $("#divContent1").hide().html(window[$(this).attr("id")]).fadeIn(500);
});
```

`$(this).attr("id")` is just a string, `window[$(this).attr("id")]` will return the global value of the var `$(this).attr("id")`

`$(".quest").click()` will register the click event on all the elements with class `.quest`, so you dont need to use `.each`.

Or if the var are local, use `eval` instead

```
$(".quest").click(function(){
    $("#divContent1").hide().html(eval[$(this).attr("id")]).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: When I try your code and click on quest12, for example, the .html() output becomes "Avantages". Not only that, but the quest12 <p> element DISAPPEARS.  

So far every reply to my post has done this.

At least I understand that I don't need an .each function.

Comment: Say I click on the <p> element with the quest12 ID. With my code, the output becomes "quest12". With your code, it becomes "Avantages". The intended result was "Blah blah blah". Reread my question if that confuses you.

Comment: I see that. Strange. Well another answered provided above worked just fine. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.each`. You can bind a handler directly to all the elements. Then to get the ID of the element, you can use `this.id`.

Instead of using global variables `quest11`, `quest12`, you should make them properties of an object:

```
var questions = {
    quest11: "blah blah",
    quest12: "blah blah blah"
};


$("#botBox").on("click", "p", function() {
    $("#divContent1").hide().html(questions[this.id]).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: When I try your code, the .html() output becomes whatever was in the <p> I clicked on. So for quest12, the output becomes "Advantages" rather than "Blah blah blah".

Comment: Oh, I missed those variables, I thought you were depending on the fact that element IDs become global variables.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it using an object instead of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divContent1").hide().html(window[this.id]).fadeIn(500);
```

As the global variables are bind to `window` object

(Assuming the `var questXX` variables are global variables)

Comment: Please don't use `$(this).attr("id")`, the DOM sends this over just fine. `this.id` is much simpler.

Comment: Sure, this was just the minimal change to resolve the original code.